# Calling IDs and Classes inside a Javascript String

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this jQuery code. What it does is when you click a div button (#logogo), it shows a resized image in the stage.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#logogo").click(function(){
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $("#bannergo").removeClass("active");
        $("#innerstage").html("<img id=\"magiclogogo\" src=\""+document.getElementById("logogo").title+"\">").hide().fadeIn('fast');
    });
});
```

What I want to happen next is that when you click on the image (hence the magiclogogo id), it would be able to show (or to load) the image in its original size.

So far I tried putting an id and tried to make a jquery function for it but it does not work.

If it's not possible, is there any probable way to be able to zoom the image to its original size?

Comment: Please paste your html code and css

Comment: That doesn’t seem like an appropriate use of the `title` attribute. Anyway, do you want to just make it a link to the full-size image, or is it necessary to handle clicks in JavaScript?

Comment: It needs to open in the same window as the website (in another div that is position: absolute and width: 100%). I'm not sure or I have never tried that with a link. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).on("click", "#magiclogogo", function(){

    // your code here
});
```

Comment: what a sorcerer. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

So, what I'm guessing is that somwhere else you have something like:

```
$('#magiclogogo').on('click', function() {
   //More code here...
}
```

If the dom element isn't loaded yet, then it will not attach the event correctly. In other words, the event must be attached once the DOM element has been loaded or attach the event to the parent and look out for the source of the event (jquery has a shorthand for this, which is the other answer).

You can use the jQuery constructor to create the element and then attach the event.

```
var image = $("<img id=\"magiclogogo\" src=\""+document.getElementById("logogo").title+"\">");

image.on('click', function(){
  //Your code here
});
```

You then can add it to your container with append.

```
 $('#innerstage').append(image);
```